# System cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I have a program in a jar file, with several csv files located in the root directory of the jar file. My code for importing the files into the program looks like this :

```
public static final String STRINGFILE = "file.csv";
```

The error says "file.csv (the system cannot find the file specified)." I'm wondering why this wouldn't work if the files were in the root directory of the jar, is there something special I need to do to access them, or is it just not possible and I still need to have the path leading to the file?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not the code for importing the file. That is only a ``String`` constant defining the filename.

Comment: Your code just declares a constant. If you wouldnt mind showing us some of your actual code, we might give an answer....

Comment: the full code doesn't matter, what I mean is when I write that as String STRINGFILE = "src/main/resources/file.csv" it works, I'm just wondering why it wouldn't when I don't include the path

Comment: @user22 "the full code doesn't matter" - do you think we are magicians? Why would we help you if you refuse to show your code after two people asked you to?

Comment: @user22, based on your comment, you are doing `new File(STRINGFILE)`.  The `src/main/resources/file.csv` indicates a maven project, and you're running from Eclipse or maven.  @fish and @GyroGearless are both right, that having the actual code where you try to open the file reduces the mindreading aspect.

Comment: try `./file.cvs` IF file is with jar file(no inside) :D

Answer (score 3):

Your example (if I extrapolate that you're doing `new File(STRINGFILE)`) will look for the file on the file system in the same directory where you run the java file, not search the classpath.

You want either [`ClassLoader.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

You get the ClassLoader by issuing something like [`this.getClass().getClassLoader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29)